# Parsing variables to function in a PHP framework

Tags: php, url-routing, variable-assignment

I am thinking of making a PHP framework, now I know roughly how MVC works and I have watched some tutorials on making basic MVC projects.

I understand that the address is example.com/controller/action/arg1/arg2/arg3
now I would like the URL to look like example.com/controller/action/arg1.arg2.arg3.
I can just implode the args to get each arg in an array.

However i'm not sure how to call the action with those args because you cant put a foreach statement inside the args of calling a function so would I need a long list of calls for the actions with different amounts of args like

```
if(count($args) == 1){call($args[0]);}
if(count($args) == 2){call($args[0], $args[1]);}
if(count($args) == 3){call($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);}
```

I'm guessing there is a much cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use periods to separate URL arguments? Just stick with the accepted convention of either slash-delimited arguments, or the user of a query string.

Comment: If you explode /users/view/1.Jack with the var / u get a nice array with controller action then args then you explode the args with . and then you get a nice array with the args :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. Take a look at [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func_array('function_name', $args);
```